# ionic serve error in mac

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, ionic-serve

I'm getting following error when I'm trying to serve the ionic project.

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/SampathM/thotilla/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/ionic-angular/app-scripts.js:9:16)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:103:16)
    at Object.importAppScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/ionic-angular/app-scripts.js:7:20)
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: have you setup the project correctly? did `npm install`?

Comment: yeh i did install it :/

Comment: what does ionic info give?

Comment: Sampaths-MacBook-Air:~ SampathM$ ionic info
[WARN] You are not in an Ionic project directory. Project context may be 
       missing.

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

System:

    Node : v9.5.0
    npm  : not installed
    OS   : macOS High Sierra

Misc:

    backend : pro

Comment: You need to run the command in your project dir

Comment: Check if there is ionic.config.json file there

Comment: yes its there im using ionic on mac

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem and I fix it executing :

```
npm i -g @ionic/app-scripts
```

after giving root permissions with `sudo su`

Hope to be helpful